# Inferring type from unknown type

Tags: java, generics

In Java, it's not possible to instantiate a collection of unknown type:

```
List<?> list1 = new ArrayList<?>()
```

gives the following error

```
required: class or interface without bounds
  found:    ?
1 error
```

But doing

```
List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

compile without errors.

My question is the following: What is the type inferred and what is the logic behind this?

Comment: [Good luck!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html)

Comment: The inferred type is `Object`. There isn't enough constraint for inference, so `Object` is picked - what else?:)